# How to call an externally defined method within a while loop in another function

Tags: ruby

This is the problem given:

Exercise 2.1

> Given a text file with multiple lines, write a program
>   to print the line with the maximum number of characters and the number of 
>   characters that it has. Assume that the input file has a distinct maximum (
>   i.e., only one line has the maximum number of characters).

This is my correct solution:

```
def file
  infile = File.open('example.txt', 'r')
  max = -1
  maxln = ''
  while (line = infile.gets)
    size = line.chomp.size
    if max < size
      max = size
      maxln = line
    end
  end
  infile.close
  puts maxln
  puts max
end

file
```

However, I want to play around with it a little so I broke up the code into different functions:

```
def initialize(max = -1, maxln = '')
  @max = max
  @maxln = ''
end

def defining_max
  if @max < @size
    @max, @maxln = @size, @line
  end
end

def building_max
  infile = File.open('example.txt', 'r')
  while (line = infile.gets)
     @size = line.chomp.size
     defining_max
  end
   infile.close
  puts @maxln
  puts @max
end

building_max
```

In `building_max` I try to call `defining_max`. How do I do that? And also, do I properly break up the code into different functions?

This is the error I got:

```
c2e1.rb:95: warning: redefining Object#initialize may cause infinite loop
c2e1.rb:101:in `defining_max': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from c2e1.rb:110:in `building_max'
from c2e1.rb:117:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is this in a class?

Comment: no, it is not in a class

Comment: Then the `initialize` method is never getting called, which is why `@max` is `nil`

Comment: everything are classes in ruby. `initialize` is the constructor method name by default,  you need to change that name cos you're overriding `Object` class constructor method. Also, as @tibsar said, you are not calling the method, hence `@max` is `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mr_sudaca is right, your @max is always nil..

maybe you'd like to try this:

```
class Discover
  def initialize
    @max = 0
    @maxln = ''
  end

  def maxNumberOf file
    infile = File.open(file, 'r')
    while (line = infile.gets)
        defining_max line
    end
    infile.close
    @maxln
  end

  private
  def defining_max line
    size = line.chomp.size
    if @max < size
        @max = size
        @maxln = line
    end
  end
end

t =  Discover.new
puts t.maxNumberOf 'example.txt'
```